# mod_rewrite for WAMP alias?

Tags: mod-rewrite, wamp

I am using WAMPServer2 for my php framework Nette.

I first copied its folder directly into www folder of WAMP. I enabled mod_rewrite module, and I have set every AllowOverride All. Everything functioned perfectly.

My problme is, than, becouse multiple project, I created alias for same project. Now, routing inside Nette framework doesent work, becouse mod_rewrite doesent. I believe there is some extra setting for Aliases. I tried to found something, but unsuccesfully. I have only little experience with modyfying apache settings. Is there a way to get it working? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had trouble with this mod_rewrite and an alias directory in WAMP today. The solution was to set RewriteBase in the .htaccess of the alias directory.

The solution is to set

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /aliasdirectory/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using an alias for a Yii project and was stuck on the rewrite forever.  RewriteBase was just what I needed!

Comment: what should I put instead of 'aliasdirectory' ?

Comment: @user1406269 the actual directory name from your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question, but my solution was as follows:
I didn't want to mange with .htaccess RewriteBase since the same file was used in production environment, where RewriteBase would need to be changed.

Instead of creating Apache alias I created a Windows symbolic link.
Instead of Apache directive

```
Alias /<alias> /<path>/<to>/<alias>/<dir>
```

I went to current webroot dir and createad

```
mklink /d <alias> /<path>/<to>/<alias>/<dir>
```

And don't need to change any other configuration (I am not sure in which directory path fall permissions).